# Php fopen write in txt file -> file empty

Tags: php, xampp

I have the following PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>mencari link dari hasil google search dan menyimpan ke file</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="wewewe" >
<div id="submit">
<input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$myfile = fopen("blogspot.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$url  = $_POST['wewewe'];
$html = file_get_html($url);

$linkObjs = $html->find('li.sidebar-item a');
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {

    $link  = trim($linkObj->href);

    // if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;    
    }
    echo   "<a href='". $link ."'>$link</a>". '</p>' ;
    fwrite ($myfile, "<a href='". $link ."'>$link</a>". '</p>'."\r\n") ;

}
fclose($myfile);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using:

- Xampp OK
- Simplehtmldom1_5 OK
- Imacros OK

I'm also having another script like this but no needed Imacros but the file is still empty. Can anyone help?

Comment: What server are you using to run this? Linux or Windows?

Comment: Im using VPS WIndows for this

Comment: According to the code. Contents will only be written to the file if you have link objects found in the HTML. If so, the links will be also be written to both the file and the immediate HTML output. So are there any output in your script through browser? Is there any link at all?

Comment: @KoalaYeung When i running my script (http://prnt.sc/ecosai) There is an output to my "htdocs" file. And my output file name is blogspot.txt but, When im opening my file there is nothing in there and only empty txt

Comment: I mean do you have link output to your browser? If no link were found by your script, there will be no content output to blogspot.txt and no links displayed to your browser.